# Get a EKEvent from a array iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to get an EKEvent from an array iOS. But I have one problem. If I put my code lines in the `viewDidLoad` method, it works.

But if I make it in a button from a table view: `(-(IBAction)button:(UiButton *)sender)` it gets an EKEvent, but doesn't note the event.

Thats my code:

```
EKEvent *event =[eventArray objectAtIndex:0]
NSString *string = event.notes
```

Thats the complete code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    selectedDate = [NSDate date];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted == NO) {

            UIViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"needAccess"];
            [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
            [self addChildViewController:controller];

        }
    }];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDate *start = [calendar dateBySettingHour:0 minute:0 second:0 ofDate:selectedDate options:0];
    NSDate *end = [calendar dateBySettingHour:0 minute:0 second:0 ofDate:[selectedDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24] options:0];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:start endDate:end calendars:nil];
    eventArray = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];


}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [eventArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"EventCell"];

    EKEvent *event = [eventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIButton *headline = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    headline.layer.cornerRadius = headline.frame.size.width / 2;
    headline.clipsToBounds = YES;

    headline.tag = indexPath.row;
    [headline addTarget:self action:@selector(headlineButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

-(void)headlineButton:(UIButton*)sender {

    EKEvent *event = [eventArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *notes = [event.notes componentsSeparatedByString:@"//"];


    NSString *latitude = [notes objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *longitude = [notes objectAtIndex:2];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because neither the cell or the button on the cell have an `EKEvent` property.

Your cell is loaded from a model.  The event data is likely in the model

If your button or cell needs to access event data, you have to decide how the data flows through your app.  You also want to have a single source of truth for the event, so no matter what your app's state, you always are certain about details for an event, whether editing or updating or persisting or deleting or inserting an event.

These are questions you may want to tackle, so you have a really good understanding where and how you store these details, and how your cell button should access an event's note.

Comment: And have you a Solution für that?

Comment: You'll have to post more code showing details about the cell and its button so people can understand the roles that the cell and button are supposed to fulfill.